# VBA nested for loop, only one loop advances

Tags: vba, excel

I've encountered a really weird issue in excel copying data from one workbook to another.
Code snippet:

```
For iRow = 7 To iMaxCheckRows
    strPartNum = thisSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value
    If strPartNum <> "" Then
        For iSourceRow = 4 To iMaxRows
            If sourceBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iSourceRow, 2).Value = strPartNum Then
                thisSheet.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = sourceBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iSourceRow, 4).Value 'here it gets stuck
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iSourceRow
    End If
Next iRow
```

Everything works as expected until the condition in the second if-statement is met for the first time. The value is copied correctly but after that it's stuck on this line. 
The iRow is incremented but the iSourceRow is not and the same value is copied until iRow reaches iMaxCheckRows.
I tried to debug it using single step but it stays on the same line with iRow incremented.

I've never seen this kind of behavior before. Does someone have a clue whats going on here?

Comment: Shouldn't `strPartNum = thisSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value` be `strPartNum = thisSheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Value`???

Comment: What is `sourceBook`? How is it referred? Is it opened?

Comment: Yes, strPartNum = thisSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value should indeed be strPartNum = thisSheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Value --Thanks!

Comment: sourceBook is an opened workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strPartNum = thisSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value should indeed be strPartNum = thisSheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Value

That did the trick. Now i feel stupid.